# how can i insert interface array's specific index in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an `angular(typescript)` app in which i have a interface like this

```
export interface PartnerCnic{
 id: string;
 shipperRegCnicFront: File;
 shipperRegCnicBack: File;
}
```

inside my component i have an array like this

```
partnerCnics: PartnerCnic[] = [];
```

Now i want to insert this interface array's non existing index. Because initially my this array will be empty. And then i have `fileUpload` function in which every time user selects a `file` so my `fileUpload` function calls in wihch i am trying to do this

```
fileUpload(index: number, key: string, dropFile: File){
  this.partnerCnics[index][key] = dropFile;
}
```

But when this function excutes so it throws me an error like this

```
Cannot set property 'shipperRegCnicFront' of undefined
```

So how can i insert a value on my interface array's specific index in typescript?

Comment: Is key the Id from the interface?

Comment: No. each time when `fileUpload` invoked so whether the key will be `shipperRegCnicFront` or `shipperRegCnicBack`

Answer (score 0):

If it's for insertion into an empty array(partnerCnics),
I think you need to proceed with the insertion of the arrangement first.

like this.partnerCnics.push({'', null, null});
and after this.fileUpload

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this using this

```
if (this.partnerCnics[index]) {
   this.partnerCnics[index][key] = dropFile;
} else {
  this.partnerCnics.push({
    shipperRegCnicFront: key === 'shipperRegCnicFront' ? dropFile : null,
    shipperRegCnicBack: key === 'shipperRegCnicBack' ? dropFile : null,
  })
}
```

In this i am first checking that if index is exist, if index exists so i directly insert the vlaue and if not i use `.push` to insert a value.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set `partnerCnics[index][key] = yourVariable` because that can go against your defined interface. See the following example.

```
interface PartnerCnic {
    id: string;
    shipperRegCnicFront: string;
    shipperRegCnicBack: string;
}

let partnerCnics: PartnerCnic[] = [{id: '1', shipperRegCnicFront: 'aa', shipperRegCnicBack: 'zz'}];

type PartnerCnicType = keyof PartnerCnic;
// OR
// type PartnerCnicType = 'shipperRegCnicFront' | 'shipperRegCnicBack';

function fileUpload(index: number, key: PartnerCnicType, dropFile: string)
{
    partnerCnics[index][key] = dropFile;
}

fileUpload(0, 'shipperRegCnicFront', 'test');
```

NOTE: I have changed `File` to `string` for this example purpose. You can keep it File of-course.

Also you can have index out range issue here. You have to change the logic in `fileUpload` function whether you are inserting in an array or make sure you are updating existing object in an array. e.g.

```
if (this.partnerCnics[index]) 
{
    this.partnerCnics[index][key] = dropFile;
}
else 
{
    let partnerNic: PartnerCnic = {} as PartnerCnic;
    partnerNic[key] = dropFile;
    this.partnerCnics.push(partnerNic);
}
```

Comment: see my own answer. I have achieved my desired output without changing the interface definition.  :) any way thanks for your try

Comment: @FahadSubzwari I changed File to string just to give you an example.